# How can I get maximum Buffer size in Node.js

Tags: node.js, v8

In Node.js 0.12.x maximum size of the buffer was limited by allocatable memory, which size could be got with:

```
require('smalloc').kMaxLength;
```

The actual value of `kMaxLength` was [hardcoded](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c8bf5c35e431d4029e084024501863a4cf907882/src/objects.h#L4647-L4648) in old versions of V8 and was equal to `0x3fffffff`.

The problem is there is no `smalloc` module in io.js >=3.x (including node.js 4.x). It was mentioned that `Buffer` implementation was rewritten in V8 4.4.x.

So, my question is: is there a way to get the maximum size of the Buffer (and/or allocatable memory) in io.js >= 3.x ?

Comment: this feels like an [XY problem statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what do you need to know the maximum buffer length for? (because Node can work with streams just fine. There should never be a reason to create a buffer so large it overruns)

Comment: I want to create a FileSystem mocks that fails on too big files (just like real `fs` module does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file "calculated" (https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/4.4.63/src/objects.h) also has fixed constant for the external array.

```
4642 // Maximal acceptable length for an external array.
4643  static const int kMaxLength = 0x3fffffff;
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like you can use 
    require('buffer').kMaxLength;

That was the change in 3.0 and still in 4.0

[b625ab4242](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/b625ab4242) - buffer: fix usage of kMaxLength (Trevor Norris) [#2003](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2003)